# c# force debug mode programmatically

Tags: c#, debugging

Nevermind why one might want to do this, I'm just curious to know if it can be done.

Here's my code that doesn't work:

```
if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    try
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        while (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Security.SecurityException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exception " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

Basically I was curious to know how to use the `Debugger.Launch()` method.

Comment: You question is not clear. Can you describe in more detail what you're looking to do?

Comment: My goal was to start the debugger programmatically, i.e. to attach it to the process that is running via the process itself.

Comment: This actually worked really well for me. I was unable to attach a debugger to a process as soon as it starts (even using gflags, vsjitdebugger, and windbg). This not only launched a VS debugger for me, but also triggered an immediate breakpoint. It also found pdbs that for whatever reason couldn't be found when manually attaching to a process (even with the correct paths set). Thank you!

Comment: @PerryC, glad it helped.  As follow up on this, based on how this is implemented: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/debugger.cs,830c527df7fc0646 , I think it was unnecessary of me to check for Debugger.IsAttached, since it already checks that under the hood.  So one Debugger.Launch() call should be enough near the entrypoint of the program, and subsequent breakpoints should be just Debugger.Break().

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Debugger.Launch will launch a debugger or will do nothing is one is already attached. I believe It's not a breakpoint. Debugger.Break() will actually break.

Calling Debugger.Launch() may do different things depending on the machine, for example if Visual Studio is installed or not, etc.

See also a related tech article: [How to: Launch the Debugger Automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Cool, I will have to take a good hard look at that article.  I am realizing now though that since I'm using VS Express, which doesn't normally have an "attach to process" command like the other visual studios, that perhaps it's not intended to work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately the link does not quite give what I was looking for, but it is a neat trick that may come in handy.

Answer (score 3):

It will launch and attaches a debugger to the process.
For sure do not use it in production . I think that possible use
can be in local machine when error occured and you want automatically run debug.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I think that it is not in fact attaching it to my process.  Perhaps it is because I am using visual studio express.

Comment: VS express doesn't include the JIT Debugger.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstanding what `Debugger.Launch()` does.  It functions like a hard-coded breakpoint.

When your program hits `Debugger.Launch()`, the Just-In-Time-Debugging window will show (assuming you have Visual Studio installed on the machine.  At that point, your program is stopped - it doesn't keep running.

If you choose an instance of VS, it will be launched, and will be stopped on the line with `Debugger.Launch()`, as if you hit a breakpoint there.

So there is really no reason for the while() loop.  You could just call `Debugger.Launch()` whenever you want to stop the program to look at something.

But the utility of `Debugger.Launch()` is questionable.  You can much more easily use breakpoints, and with breakpoints there is no danger of accidentally leaving it in the finished product.

Comment: From msdn on Debugger.Launch() - "Launches and attaches a debugger to the process."  Perhaps you are thinking Debugger.Break()?  I think Simon Mourier would back me up on this, based on his answer.

Comment: @user420667: Nope - I didn't read the docs.  I coded up a quick one-line app to test it.  If you run it under VS, it behaves exactly like a breakpoint.  But if you launch outside of VS, it behaves exactly how I described it.  It's possible our machines behave differently based on the different VS components installed or whatnot, but those are the results I got.

Comment: That's odd, when I run it in VS 2008 express and VS 2008, it doesn't force a stop (when started in either debug mode or non-debug mode).  Only Debugger.Break() forces a stop when I run it, and that's when it's in debug mode.  When I run it in VS 2008, Debugger.Launch() does prompt an exception, and asks to launch a debugger.

Comment: This works for me with VS2008. I even compiled the code outside of VS (using csc.exe) since I have a whole bunch of small test scripts. I don't want to have to have a separate project for each test script, but I want to debug in VS if something goes wrong. I just put the Debugger.Launch() into the code that isn't working and it pops up in VS.

Comment: I know this old but I just wanted to comment. This is helpful in service startup for not putting waits in your code so that you can attach a debugger. Normally this just sits in our code until we want to debug that section and not race to attach it on service startup. It also works good for MVC apps while they are starting up because my break points don't get hit until after startup.